# Using attr function dynamically

Tags: r, dynamic-programming, attr

Considering the following data frame

```
df<-data.frame(a=c(1,2,3))
```

I can show it by doing:

```
df
```

or

```
get("df")
```

Also, I can give an attribute to it by doing this:

```
attr(df,"anyAttribute")<-"df attribute"
attributes(df)
$names
[1] "a"

$class
[1] "data.frame"

$row.names
[1] 1 2 3

$anyAttribute
[1] "df attribute"
```

Is there any way to give attributes to dataframes dynamically?. What I want is something like this:

```
> attr(get("df"),"anyAttribute")<-"df attribute"
Error in attr(get("df"), "anyAttribute") <- "df attribute" : 
  destino de la asignación se expande a un objeto fuera del lenguaje
```

Comment: You may need  `assign`

Comment: If you are new to R, I would strongly suggest you avoid using `get`/`assign`. Often people end up using those function when trying to do things like they would in a different language rather than doing things in an R-like way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `assign` to update the original object

```
tmp <- get('df')
attr(tmp, 'anyAttribute') <- 'df attribute'
assign('df', tmp)
```

-output

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ a: num  1 2 3
 - attr(*, "anyAttribute")= chr "df attribute"
```

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean this?

```
r <- `attr<-`(get("df"), "anyAttribute", "df attribute")

attributes(r)
# $names
# [1] "a"
# 
# $class
# [1] "data.frame"
# 
# $row.names
# [1] 1 2 3
# 
# $anyAttribute
# [1] "df attribute"
```